# Problema al leer el día en una fecha, siempre devuelve 11

Tags: java

Estoy capturando una variable de una base de datos, una fecha, pero solo necesito el día y cuando la pongo en un `jLabel` me sale siempre el número 11 pero cuando llamo toda la fecha si aparece bien no entiendo.

El código es:

```
SimpleDateFormat fechaingreso = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date fecha100 = null;
try {
    fecha100 = fechaingreso.parse(fechapago);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
}

Calendar calendar5 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar5.setTime(fecha100);
String fechacon100 = fechaingreso.format(calendar5.getTime());
diamensualidad.setText(fechacon100);`
```

Necesitaría que solo llamara el día de esa fecha pero me sale siempre 11 no se por qué, pero cuando llamo toda la fecha si sale bien.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, esta pregunta es interesante, pero hay algunas cosas que no están claras, ¿qué lenguaje es éste? Parece Java. Deberías editar la pregunta para añadirlo como etiqueta (en lugar de la de netbeans que debería ser usada sólo para preguntas específicas de ese IDE), así como poner un título más descriptivo, y ejemplos de fechas que has probado. Lee [ask] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio.

Comment: Es java el lenguaje y la variable fechapago es de una tabla que tengo en una base de datos con una fecha, basicamente necesito que me muestre en un jLabel el dia de esa fecha

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene la fecha en la base de datos? ¿Y si imprimes el valor de `fechapago`, qué ves?

Comment: Es necesario que muestres como obtienes "fechapago" y de que tipo es "diamensualidad". Puedes agregar la firma del metodo o como invocas a JLabel?